# Liferay getting URL params issue

Tags: java, jsp, url, liferay, url-parameters

I have a page in which I have deployed a portlet, in my portlet I access some params using the url in the browser like:

```
localhost.com:8080/mypage?text=helloworld
```

with using

```
PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(request).getParameter("text")
```

and it is working fine.

The issue comes when there is some latency in `view.jsp` rendering (like putting some debugger in Java code) and in the meanwhile the render portlet `view.jsp` is called again but this time I cannot read the "text" param from request

From client side the url being called is as follows:

```
> http://localhost:8080/c/portal/render_portlet?p_l_id=92438&p_p_id=editor_WAR_heliumportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_t_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_pos=0&p_p_col_count=2&p_p_isolated=1&currentURL=
> ...
```

This url doesn't contain my param, I can't find a clue from where this url is triggered. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liferay can push portlets to be rendered asynchronously if they take too long to load (e.g. when attached to a debugger). This is due to the default values for [`render-weight` and `ajaxable`](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/definitions/liferay-portlet-app_6_2_0.dtd.html#render-weight), which allow this. Change them in `liferay-portlet.xml`.

Also note that fetching generic HTTP parameters that are not namespaced is not part of the spec, that's why Liferay doesn't care to forward the non-namespaced-parameter from the original URL to your portlet when it rendered it via AJAX. In other words: By using this technique you're probably preparing yourself for quite some more trouble in future.

Comment: if i turn ajaxable false is it completely safe or it depends on my implementation?

Comment: yes, it's safe. I'm not aware of any drawbacks other than your debugger (or slow rendering) will necessarily affect the whole page's load time.

Comment: thanks, and if i use namespace parameters i cannot get them in my jsp file on browser's refresh call??

Answer (score 0):

As far as portlets can share the same page with other portlets, portlets use to have a prefix or a namespace.

This namespace can be always the same for a given portlet if this portlet is not instanceable. Or this namespace ca be variable with the purpose of being unique for each instance of the portlet.

So, the parameters for a portlet must be prefixed with the namespace.

Then, it will be easy to access this param using util tools like..

```
ParamUtil.get(renderRequest, "paramName", "defValue");
```

Here the java doc

https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs-all/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/ParamUtil.html

Regards